# Methods to improve neural network distinguish red from blue?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, scikit-learn, deep-learning

I have a lot of data for red and blue where I'm trying to distinguish red data from blue, but they all look like this basically (see Imgur). Overlapping a lot, but having peaked in different places

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsYVc.png

They overlap a lot, and I can only get roc auc score of 0.65.

So far in terms of data-processing I've only used class weights to balance it. I have tried different kinds of dense/dropout networks, with the different features but only 0.65 is the best I can get, most hover around 0.63-0.65, no matter how many layers or epochs I add.

For example a simple DNN/dropout yields 0.65:

```
    Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    Dropout(0.3),
    Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    Dropout(0.3),
    Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    Dropout(0.3),
    Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    Dropout(0.3),
    Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")
```

Some resnet modification I found online also only provided 0.65.

So I have tried CNN and dense layer networks only, so far.

What kind of methods could I try to more clearly have the neural network distinguish red from the blue?

Comment: Might be more appropriate on https://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML methodology and practice.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description it's not clear why you believe there should be a better score. Instead of changing the model you should focus on features. Based on what red and blue represent why do you believe they are different? Can you tell that story using the features before you attempt to estimate parameters for a classifier?

You should also consider the application for the result. There are some scenarios where a score of 0.5 is incredible and other applications where anything less than 0.9999 is abject failure.

In my experience presenting a model, even if it appears to be doing an incredible job, without a clear story will be met with skepticism at best. At worst it will affect the presenters credibility.

Comment: If you get a score of 0.5 it is the same as coin tossing, and basically worthless.

Comment: That's not necessarily true. If I could pick stocks that doubled in value within a year at a 50% success rate I would be on a beach.